# difference between r squared and standard error

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Can someone explain to me in simple terms with an example scenario, the difference between R-squared and standard error.

Let's say I am predicting the house price based on the house size. If my r-squared is 0.60. This means that the house size determines 60% in the variation of house price.

And if my standard error = 5.9, what does this mean in this context?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about statistics and mathematics instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regression anaylsis, both R-squared and standard error are measures of the goodness-of-fit.

As you correctly noted, a R-squared of 60% can be interpreted as house size explaining 60% of the variation in house prices.

Whilst a standard error of 5.9 (assuming you work in units of millions) can be interpreted as meaning that the model you have fitted will, based on a certain house size, output house prices that on average deviate from your data by 5.9 millions.

Answer (score 1):

The expression *standard error* is frequently used to describe the standard deviation of a quantity under consideration.

If in your case the standard error refers to the house price, then the empirical standard deviation of your house prices will be 5.9.

The r-squared is computed as 1 minus the quotient of the mean-squared error and the variance of your dependent variable.

In particular, for the house-price example, you can conclude that the mean-squared error equals  (1-0.6)*5.9*5.9=13.92